# Get orientation Exif tag from photo

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to detect the orientation of a photo taken by native camera. This is my code:

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
String orientation = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);

if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT == Integer.parseInt(orientation)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Portrait! " + orientation);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Landscape! " + orientation);
}
```

However, if I take a photo in portrait mode, `Landscape! 6` is printed. And if I take it in landscape mode, `Portrait! 1` is printed.

Compile and target SDK versions are 21. In `android.content.res.Configuration` class there are these two constants:

```
public static final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = 1; 
public static final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 2;
```

Why am I getting `1` when landscape and `6` when portrait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use "ExifInterface.getAttributeInt() or getAttribute()..."
```

This method is to get correct value of image in which angle you need to rotate.

```
 - "ExifInterface.getAttributeInt" will returns angle of rotation you
   need to make,not portrait or landscape

See the following snippet for your  understanding.

    ExifInterface exif = null;
           try {
               exif = new ExifInterface(path);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           try {
               switch (exif
                       .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1)) {
                   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                       return 180;
                   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                       return 90;
                   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                       return 270;
                   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                       return 0;
                   default:
                       return 0;
               }
           } catch (NullPointerException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return 0;
```

Comment: I understand now. Thanks!